# A Tricky Objective-C Blocks Behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'd be glad to get explanation for the following behavior:

```
typedef void (^MyBlock)(void);
MyBlock g_ary[4];

int runBlockParam2(MyBlock callbackBlock, int num) {
    g_ary[num] = callbackBlock;
    return num+100;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
            __block int j;
            int k = runBlockParam2(^{
                NSLog(@"in the block i=%i, j=%i", i, j);
            }, i);
            j=k;
        }
        for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
            g_ary[i]();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code shows the following output:

`in the block i=0, j=100
in the block i=1, j=101
in the block i=2, j=102
in the block i=3, j=103`

Why is `j` modified by the assignment which follows the block?

It is interesting to mention that if we remove the `__block` modifier, we will get this:

`in the block i=0, j=0
in the block i=1, j=100
in the block i=2, j=101
in the block i=3, j=102`

I'll appreciate any explanation to the above behavior!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__block` storage type causes any changes to the variable outside of the block to be seen inside of the block and vice-versa.  Your `j = k` line runs before the block itself is run in your second for loop so the block sees `j` after it has been assigned.

Removing the `__block` causes the block to capture the value of `j` as it is when the block is created which is before the assignment.  You're invoking undefined behavior after removing the `__block` because you are capturing `j` before it has been initialized which leads to the strange output.

If you change your declaration to `int j = 0` then the log statements would all show `j=0` as you would expect.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But `j` keeps going up in the next cycles, so why don't they all become 103, as the last value assigned to `j` before leaving the scope of the `j` variable?

Comment: You are redeclaring `j` inside the loop so each block has its own `j` that it is referring to. If you move the `__block int j;` outside of the loop then all the blocks will print `j=103`

Comment: Thanks @dan. I'll accept your answer. That means that a `__block` variable is actually a static variable within the block, but as long as the scope of its declaration exists, it can be accessed outside of the block!

Answer (score 0):

with __block the j variable will be passed into block as a pointer so if you call the block after the assignment `j=k` j is 100 now.

without __block only the j variable's value is passed into block. block itself couldn't change j after the block definition in which the value is passed. so j is 0